# How to shutdown and reboot the emulator through code in android?

Tags: java, android

I have implemented the code like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_REBOOT);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

it get the error(runtime):

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.REBOOT from pid=*** and uid=***
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal SDK applications cannot cause phones to shut down or reboot. Only applications that are part of the firmware (i.e., signed by the firmware sining key) can hold the proper permission and perform those actions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, and I think there are (and should be) a lot of restrictions on rebooting from code. But you can try to check the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
```

and from [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg50073.html) I read you might need some extra undocumented stuff:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_REBOOT);
i.putExtra("nowait", 1);
i.putExtra("interval", 1);
i.putExtra("window", 0);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Take special notice of the sentence in that link:

> Not only is it not in the API docs,
>   but because as you say you need to be
>   signed with the platform cert, you can
>   only use this if you are running on a
>   device whose system software you have
>   built yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In android SDK documents, I see a note about the Intent.ACTION_REBOOt. It says, "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system". 
I think you don't have the  privilege to use this intent to reboot the device for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this. However, u need to install busybox.

```
public static boolean selfShutdown() {
    boolean bOK = false;
    String telnetCmd = "busybox telnet 10.0.2.2 5554";
    String cmd = "kill";

    try {
        String out = String.format("telnetCmd=%s", telnetCmd);
        Log.i(TAG+".selfShutdown", out);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(telnetCmd);
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        String command = String.format("%s\n", cmd);
        os.writeBytes(command);
        os.flush();
        out = String.format("%s", "complete os.flush()");
        Log.i(TAG+".selfShutdown", out);
        p.waitFor();
        out = String.format("%s", "complete p.waitFor()");
        Log.i(TAG+".selfShutdown", out);
        bOK = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bOK;
}
```